# Parameter in query graphql breaking JSON with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

my script connects to a graphql API by fetch and inserts the JSON return in the postgresql database, however when I insert the primaryLabels parameter into the query, it returns that my JSON is broken by a token>.
If I remove this parameter, everything goes perfectly, any solution?
I tried to turn the query into a string, but the code still fails

**Code**

```
let queryAPI = {"query": `{squads {name cards(includedOnKanban: true, closed: false, archived: false, cancelled: false, updatedSince: \"2020-01-01T00:00:00-0300\") { identifier title description status priority assignees { fullname email } secondaryLabel primaryLabels swimlane workstate}}}`};

(async () => {

    try {

        const rawResponse = await fetch('https://www.bluesight.io/graphql', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Bluesight-API-Token': 'token-here'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(queryAPI)
        });

        const content = await rawResponse.json();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    at async C:\Users\Documents\Autoportal\Bluesight\index.js:35:25 {
  name: 'FetchError',
  message: 'invalid json response body at https://www.bluesight.io/graphql reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0',        
  type: 'invalid-json'
```

**JSON result example:**

> {
>       "data": {
>           "squads": [
>               {
>                   "name": "SUPPORT IT",
>                   "cards": [
>                       {
>                           "identifier": "06x38y",
>                           "title": "ALL - Validate data",
>                           "description": "review database.",
>                           "status": null,
>                           "priority": "medium",
>                           "assignees": [
>                               {
>                                   "fullname": "Carlos",
>                                   "email": "carlos@br.it.com",
>                               }
>                           ],
>                           "secondaryLabel": null,
>                           "primaryLabels": [
>                               "CLIENT"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   ]
>               }
>           ]
>       } }

**CONTENT**

```
{
  squads: [ { name: 'SUPPORT IT', cards: [Array] } ]
}
```

Comment: Since we can't reproduce the problem it would be double-useful to have as much information as possible: could you show the stacktrace of the error? Could you minimize the code in a way that only problematic part is visible?

Comment: can you try printing the content of the variable? this is most likely a escaping char problem, you need to encode you parameters using encodeURIComponent

Comment: I rephrased the question guys

Comment: @ItaloAyres I add variable

Comment: Can I help with any more information? Sorry for the poorly worded question

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` this is how an html would start. Are you sure you're not getting an error page from nginx or something?

Comment: How I can validate?

Comment: which line is the line #35?

Comment: line 35: const content = await rawResponse.json();

Comment: sorry for the delay!

Comment: The JSON result example you posted have two errors: missing `"` at `"title": "ALL - Validate data,` and missing `,` before `"secondaryLabel"`

Comment: @LuisHenrique `console.log(JSON.stringify(rawResponse))` right after you fetch it. And you'll most probably see an HTML

Comment: The json example has been changed to the correct format, likely to change data removed from something without notice, customer data cannot be exported

Comment: JSON.stringify() = {"url":"https://www.bluesight.io/graphql","status":200,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"_headers":{"server":["openresty/1.15.8.1"],"date":["Tue, 17 Mar 2020 12:09:33 GMT"],"content-type":["application/json; charset=utf-8"]  ... The output is too big to post in the comments, this is a piece of it

Comment: @LEQADA The today did not show the error, could it be some garbage that was in memory?